# How can I delete images from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete images from firebase storage.

This is my Firebase Database.

[image]

Comment: You need to create a `DatabaseReference` that points to the node you want to delete, and then call `removeValue()` on it. If you're having a hard time making that work, show the [minimal complete code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you please write the code for this database?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I've given you the two basic ingredients. If you're having a hard time making it work from that, show what you've tried and what result you got.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this method call:

```
StorageReference photoRef = mFirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(mImageUrl);
```

Then delete as you were:

```
photoRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
    // File deleted successfully
    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: deleted file");
}
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: did not delete file");
}});
```

Comment: What will be in mImageUrl?

Comment: it was the link of image you have been saved in realtimedatabase ... you can get it easily by make search in database and get it's link's

Comment: Can you please write the storage reference for this database??